# "rails generate plugin" gives "Could not find generator plugin."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I can't find a clear resource tell me how to generate a rails 3 plugin.
When I run

```
rails generate plugin [your_plugin_name]
```

I got this error
    Could not find generator plugin.
I think generating plugin skeleton have different command than this! but what is it?

Comment: Ok, the plugin should be generated like this "rails plugin new [your_plugin_name]"
in your vendor/plugins folder

Comment: also it's deprecated to make plugins this way, please read [HOW TO CONVERT SIMPLE RAILS 2.3 STYLE PLUGINS FOR RAILS 3.2](http://code.coneybeare.net/how-to-convert-simple-rails-23-style-plugins) in order not to use the deprecated method!

Comment: You might want to sum your findings up in an answer and accept it to close this questions.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the plugin should be generated like this "rails plugin new [your_plugin_name]" in your vendor/plugins folder.

also it's deprecated to make plugins this way, please read [HOW TO CONVERT SIMPLE RAILS 2.3 STYLE PLUGINS FOR RAILS 3.2](http://code.coneybeare.net/how-to-convert-simple-rails-23-style-plugins) in order not to use the deprecated method!

best of LUCK ...